# Grouping MySQL tables in phpMyAdmin into folders

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, directory

So yes, not asking how to use group by...but rather sorting the many tables in my ever growing database.

Is it possible to Place 10 or so tables into Project folders so that it's easier to find the table I'm after when working with the GUI?